# localizing ArcGIs map using dojo

Tags: localization, dojo, arcgis

According to this document, Arcgis map is localizable using dojo, I have installed dojo and tried changing the locale as said in the document but map's language does not get changed!!

Comment: you forgot to add link to the document

Comment: First it's unclear what you're asking , second no document was attached to your post , please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question

Comment: Please add some more information to your Post! It's unclear what you are asking and your Document is missing. To add some code, so we can see what you have tried so far would be nice too.

Comment: Sorry forgot to attach the link to the document:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/localization.html